# How to delete post from JSON using react js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I want to create react js application that can create, delete and edit posts. For now I managed to make add new posts but deleting single post is not working. 
This is just a piece of code that is used to submit posts and delete posts:

```
handlePostSubmit: function(post) {
  var posts = this.state.data;
  post.id = Date.now();
  var newPosts = posts.concat([post]);
  this.setState({data: newPosts});
  $.ajax({
    url: this.props.url,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: post,
    success: function(data) {
      this.setState({data: data});
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      this.setState({data: posts});
      console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
    }.bind(this)
  });
},

delc: function(post){
  var index = this.state.data.indexOf(post);
  var newData = React.addons.update(this.state.data, { $splice: [[index, 1]] });

  this.setState({ data: newData });
  $.ajax({
    url: this.props.url,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(data) {
      this.setState({data: data});
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      this.setState({data: newData});
      console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
    }.bind(this)
  });
}
```

Where I do mistake?

Comment: You've got a syntax errors - you should surround function literals with parentheses before you calling .bind(this) on them.

Comment: Can you give me example? This works perfectly for handlePostSubmit but fo delc doesn't work and doesn't give me any error.

Comment: That is how it should be:
{
  success: **(** function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
  } **)**.bind(this)
}

Comment: Doesn't work in that way, I have error: 'Unexpected token'